# Can I mount an xml-file using powershell

Tags: xml, powershell, mount

I am currently exploring powershell. I like the way I can mount everything, for example the registry, so I can use it like a file system (with ls and cd). My question is: Is there a way I can mount an xml file? If not, can you recommend an approach for creating a program to do so?

Comment: I think you know it but you can parse it with [XML] (xmldocument) : `$a = [xml](Get-Content somefile.xml)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK, there is no native method to do that. Also, I have not come across a module that can help you do that.

Jim (@beefarino) has a good set of articles on how to create PS Providers. http://www.beefycode.com/post/Creating-a-PowerShell-Provider-pt-1-Creating-the-Drive.aspx

Check this series. It may be of some help.

Comment: At first glance, writing an XML provider seems like an interesting project.  I wonder how you could elegantly handle nodes that have multiple children with the same name.